# How do I shift content up when I am animating Toolbar out?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I have a layout identical to the Play Store where I have a Toolbar, Tab Strip, and ViewPager all in a vertical LinearLayout. I want to achieve the quick return pattern of the Play Store where the Toolbar hides but the TabStrip and ViewPager stay but animate up with the Toolbar.

I have the animating Toolbar part down using animate().translateY() but I can't get the content to shift up with it (at least not smoothly). I've tried something like:

```
<FrameLayout>

    <Toolbar (with WindowActionBarOverlay = true)>

    <LinearLayout paddingTop = Toolbar_height>

         *Contains all the stuff I don't want to hide*

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

But this doesn't make the content shift up either. So I tried setting the Top Padding of the LinearLayout to 0 after I animate the Toolbar but that is instantaneous rather than animating with the ToolBar. So I tried to animate the entire LinearLayout instead using animate().translateY() but that is a bit laggy and has some unwanted side effects.

Anyone have any ideas? For RecyclerView and preferably a minSDK of 15.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an animator listener on the toolbar's translation to update the padding. Back-of-napkin code:

```
toolbar.animate()
    .translateY(-toolbar.getHeight())
    .setUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()) {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            contentView.setPadding(
                contentView.getPaddingLeft(),
                // The padding is the inverse of the animation progress.
                toolbar.getHeight() * (1f - animation.getAnimatedFraction()),
                contentView.getPaddingRight(),
                contentView.getPaddingBottom());
        }

    });
```

I'd be interested to see what the performance is like updating the layout on each animation frame like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is noticeable lag, similar to when I tried to animate the entire contentView up.

Comment: How about animating the margins instead of  the padding? It's a little bit more boilerplate (`getLayoutParams`, then modifying that, and calling `setLayoutParams`), but it's worth a shot.